# Make some buttons enable and other Disable

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a treeView with multiple nodes
-folders
-files
-lists
I have already added several buttons in my interface

- btn 1, btn2, and btn3 for the folders node
- btn4, btn5 and btn6 for the files node
- btn7 for list node

I want when I click on a node, only the buttons of this node are displayed and not the others

I tried this:

```
if ( node Folder is clicked)
{
btn1.IsEnable =true;
btn2.IsEnable =true;
btn3.IsEnable =true;
btn4.IsEnable =false;
btn5.IsEnable =false;
......

}
if ( node file is clicked)
{
btn1.IsEnable =false;
btn2.IsEnable =false;
btn3.IsEnable =false;
btn4.IsEnable =true;
btn5.IsEnable =true;
......

}
if ( node list is clicked)
{
btn1.IsEnable =false;
btn2.IsEnable =false;
btn3.IsEnable =false;
btn4.IsEnable =false;
btn5.IsEnable =false;
......

btn7.IsEnable =true;
}
```

I want another easier and optimized method

Comment: The fact your buttons are named btn1, btn2, btn3 etc. is probably a good indication they should be in some kind of collection

Comment: It's not clear what your UI looks like and how it is implemented. [How do I ask a good question?.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MadaraUtchi, can you please give any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

you can set them once using method (property assignments in the method are chained):

```
private void SetActiveButtons(string selection)
{
    btn1.IsEnable =
    btn2.IsEnable =
    btn3.IsEnable = selection == "Folder";
    
    btn4.IsEnable =
    btn5.IsEnable = 
    btn6.IsEnable = selection == "File";
    
    btn7.IsEnable = selection == "List";
}
```

then call the method with correct argument:

```
if (node folder is clicked)
{
    SetActiveButtons("Folder");
}
else if (node file is clicked)
{
    SetActiveButtons("File");
}
else if (node list is clicked)
{
    SetActiveButtons("List");
}
```